# How to determine root directory for a project using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an app ("foo") created in PHP that uses composer to bring it its dependancies. Once of the dependancies is another project ("bar") that we created.

When *bar* is added, by composer, to the *foo* app, *bar* needs access to the MySQL database of the *foo* app. The database credentials are stored in a config directory in the *foo* app.

My file structure for *foo* looks somewhat like this:

`app/          # files for the foo app
config/        # config information to access MySQL
vendor/        # composer-managed files, including our bar app
composer.json  # information to load bar into the vendor/ directory`

When I'm developing the *bar* app on its own, I need to be able to place a config/ directory at the root of my *bar* development app and *bar* needs to be able to access it. If *bar* is part of another composer project (*foo*, in this case), I need *bar* to know to go to the root of *foo* for the config/ directory, not look in the root of *bar*.

How can *bar* determine the correct directory for config/? I think I need to find the root directory of the composer install, but I don't know how to do that.

In case a real-world example would help...

I'm deploying this *foo* app to Amazon OpsWorks. OpsWorks places an opsworks.php file in the root of the deployed app. I need my submodules (*bar* in my example above) to know where to access the opsworks.php file at the root of the composer project. I need to account for the fact that composer may be set to not place *bar* in /vendor/, but might have a different file structure setup.

In other words, I want to ask Composer where the root for the app is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use composer's very own `\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile();` to get to the project root directory:

`$projectRootPath = dirname(\Composer\Factory::getComposerFile());`

And with your case, you can access your `config/` directory by:

`$configPath = $projectRootPath . '/config'`

Don't forget to add `composer` to your dependencies for the `\Composer\Factory::class` to be available:

`$ composer require composer/composer`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

The section for autoload describes the behaviour you appear to be looking for.

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Acme\\Test\\', __DIR__);
```

You can define the root of foo and the root of bar in this way and only load the items you need.